# Debug specific PropertyGroup in csproj file

Tags: .net-core, csproj

Is it possible to have a section of my csproj file in dotnet core (3.1.1) which is only included when debugging?  I'd like to accomplish something like the following

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>  <!--always valid-->
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
    <AssemblyName>SomeAssembly</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Some.Root.Namespace</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup> <!--Debugonly-->        
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>

....
</Project>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use conditional `PropertyGroup`:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <!--Debugonly-->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This also applies to <ItemGroup> so you can have dependencies included in debug but not release. I used this since my dev machine is macOS and the release environment is Windows and I was working with Pdfium which is OS specific.